# Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - MFC Application

Tags: c++

I came across with this error.Steps to reproduce error are as follows:
1. create a project **MFC Application** using Visual C++
2. I have external library files which i have included in project.
3. Also added all .dll files in Debug folder.
4. Right click the project,choose Properties from the shortcut menu and Choose 
   Configuration Properties > Linker > Input and set **Additional Dependencies** to  **IVS_SDK.lib**, Click OK.
5. Design MFC GUI and After the GUI design is complete then we add the code by 
   double clicking the Init button

```
IVS_INT32 iRet = IVS_SDK_Init();
if (IVS_SUCCEED == iRet)
{
AfxMessageBox("OK");
} else
{
CString strErrorMsg;
strErrorMsg.Format("IVS_SDK_Init failed, errno = %d", iRet);
AfxMessageBox(strErrorMsg);
} return;
```

but while running the code we are facing the error on line  IVS_INT32 iRet = IVS_SDK_Init();

Error says 
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__IVS_SDK_Init@0 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CHelloWorldDlg::OnBnClickedButtonInit(void)" (?OnBnClickedButtonInit@CHelloWorldDlg@@QAEXXZ).

I have added all the required libraries which is required for the project with required settings.
Please help me with the solution. 
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: I would recheck the `IVS_SDK.lib` step. It looks like you are missing a link to a IVS library. Did you add this library to the Debug configuration? Is there a different library for Release than Debug?